# Initialize vector of pointers to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have troubles initializing a vector of pointers to pointers (which I shouldn't do anyways I guess but please forgive me). 
I basically have a pointer `z` to a variable containing `0` and now I want to initialize a matrix that contains pointers to that pointer.

```
void example(int nrow, int ncol) {
    int zero = 0;
    int* z = &zero;
    int size = nrow * ncol;
    vector<int **> pointerMatrix(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int** a = &z;       
        pointerMatrix.push_back(a);
    }
    //following line throws an exception:
    cout << **pointerMatrix[0] << endl;
}
```

Now the above code throws an exception, apparently there is nothing to be found under the address the pointer points to.

Anyone sees my mistake?

Comment: `pointerMatrix.size()` is already `size` before the loop. I call TYPO.

Comment: Why use a vector on the first level only and it seems you have an additional pointer, which is a 3 dimensional tensor - wouldn't vector<vector<int> > solve your issue without resorting to raw pointers in the first place ?

Comment: @darune OP is a three-stars programmer 8-)

Comment: @LogicStuff so true

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
vector<int **> pointerMatrix(size);
```

should be like

```
vector<int **> pointerMatrix;
```

Seems like there is a typo mistake in your implementation as pointer matrix seems already a size before the loop. you should either push a pointer value in index or dynamically push this. For this i guess, declaring vector pointerMatrix without defining size should works.

Comment: This just calls for reallocations.

Comment: While this code may solve the immediate problem, it would be better to include some context, explaining why it works. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Please [edit] your answer and add some explanation.

Comment: @Mika Prouk asked about any mistake in his code. So i thought just pointing the line of his code which i thought not appropriate is enough. I will keep this in mind in future. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) `pointerMatrix(size);` creates a vector with having `size` amount of default-initialized (`nullptr`) elements, hence after the loop, your vector contains `2*size` elements, having the first half filed in as `nullptr`, and the second half filed in as actual elements, hence `cout << **pointerMatrix[0] << endl;` tries to dereference a `nullptr`.

To fix this, you can, either, call `reserve`, to avoid unnecessary reallocations:

```
vector<int **> pointerMatrix;
pointerMatrix.reserve (size);
```

Or use `operator[]` to assign the values, instead of pushing them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int** a = &z;       
    pointerMatrix[i] = a; // Or pointerMatrix[i] = &z;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`push_back` is used to add a new element *past the end* of the vector. It effectively increases the size of the vector to add the element at the end.

You already specified the size of your vector, so you can just access (and modify) the elements with `operator[]` for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    pointerMatrix[i] = &z;
}
```

Alternatively, use a range-based for loop:

```
for (auto& entry : pointerMatrix) { // auto& can be replaced with int**&
    entry = &z;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocate an array with the desired size, and then still use `push_back` to add further elements at the end.

Since you intend to fill the whole array with the same element, you should use this:

```
vector<int **> pointerMatrix(size, &z);
```

Comment: The original intent probably isn't to have a whole vector of pointers to the same address.